# pattern recognition - "is this a pattern?"

Tags: c, vector

I have a large vector of numbers, say 500 numbers. I would like a program to detect patterns (reoccurrence in this case) in such vector based on following rules:

**A sequence of numbers is a pattern if:**

- The size of the sequence is between 3 and 20 numbers.
- The RELATIVE positions of the numbers in sequence is repeated at
  least one other time in a vector. So let's say if I have a sequence
  (1,4,3) and then (3,6,5) somewhere else in the vector then (1,4,3) is
  a pattern. (as well as (2,5,4), (3,6,5) etc.)
- The sequences can't intersect. So, a vector (1,2,3,4,5) does not
  contain patterns (1,2,3) and (3,4,5)(we can't use the same number for
  both sequences).  However, (1,2,3,3,4,5) does contain a pattern
  (1,2,3) (or (3,4,5))
- A subset A of a pattern B is a pattern ONLY IF A appears somewhere
  else outside B. So, a vector (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,2,3,4,5) would contain
  patterns (1,2,3,4) and (1,2,3), because (1,2,3,4) is repeated (in a
  form of (2,3,4,5)) and (1,2,3) is repeated (in a form (7,8,9)).
  However, if  the vector was (1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5) the only pattern will
  be (1,2,3,4), because (1,2,3) appeares only in context of (1,2,3,4).

I'd like to know several things:

First of all I hope the rules don't go against each other. I made them myself so there might be a clash somewhere that I didn't notice, please let me know if you do notice it.

Secondly, how would one implement such system in the most efficient way? Maybe someone can point out towards some particular literature on the subject? I could go number by number starting with searching a sequence repetition for all subsets of 3, then 4,5 and till 20. But that seems to be not very efficient..
I am interested in implementation of such system in C, but any general guidance is very welcome.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 500 isn't a very large vector, so I would write something that works first without much regard for performance. That way, you have something to test the later, "better", implementations against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple of observations:

If you're interested in relative values, then your first step should be to calculate the differences between adjacent elements of the vector, e.g.:

```
Original numbers:
1   4   3   2   5   1   1   3   6   5   6   2   5   4   4   4   1   4   3   2
*********                   *********       *********           *********
Difference values:
  3   -1  -1  3   -4  0   2   3   -1  1   4   3   -1  -3  0   -3  3   -1  -1
  ******                      ******          ******              ******
```

Once you've done that, you could use an [autocorrelation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) method to look for repeated patterns in the data. This can be computed in *O*(*n* log *n*) time, and possibly even faster if you're only concerned with exact matches.

Comment: Just found this paper, also very helpful. I'll leave it here in case someone is interested.http://ismir2004.ismir.net/proceedings/p046-page-246-paper148.pdf